# How to emulate HtmlUnit driver as Firefox 9?

Tags: selenium, htmlunit, firefox-9

I am using HtmlUnit driver in my selenium tests. As mentioned in the documentation,

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

This will cause the HtmlUnit Driver to emulate Firefox 3.6’s JavaScript handling by default."
```

But, I want to make sure my app works in Firefox-9. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you really want to achieve. You can always use

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

which will open new instance of Firefox. But I am not quite sure if its solution for you

Comment: This will invoke the Firefox. This FirefoxDriver can emulate upto version 8. But I want to run the tests headless. So only I chose HtmlUnitDriver.

Comment: I know. I did read the HTMLUnitDriver javadoc and it seems that they can emulate only IE and FF, up to version 3.6 highest...